# SonarQube issue with public static variables | JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, sonarqube

I'm having an issue with SonarQube while using `public static` variables, the problem is that SonarQube want that to be `public static final`, this variable is being filled in other parts of the code, it is "dynamically" (filled with environment variable) then is used in all other classes.

This is the arrayList variable

```
public static List<String> listPersons = new ArrayList<>();
```

Errors by Sonar:

```
1- Make this "public static listPersons" field final
2- Make listPersons a static final constant or non-public and provide accessors if needed
3- Make this member "protected"
```

What's the best approach to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can have the (reference of) the variable `final` and still have its *contents* dynamically filled at some later point:

```
public static final List<String> listPersons = new ArrayList<>();

//...

public void initialize() {
    List<String> contents = populateContentsFromEnvironmentVariable();
    listPersons.addAll(contents);
}
```

However, using a "mutable-content" constant such as this one introduces possible problems. For example, you need to make sure that client code doesn't read the list before it has been populated. You might want to reconsider your design so that environment-specific properties are only initialized once and preferably encapsulated so that they are accessed through accessor methods instead of static constants; this would also allow lazy, on-demand initialization, caching etc.

Comment: I've tried that and get fixed just a part but now I have this another one: 
`Make this member "protected".` it want to make listPersons as protected...

Comment: Is the variable `public static final` or just `public static`? It should be the former.

Comment: is public static final

Comment: Then if it's only used within the same package (or subclasses), you can lower the visibility to `protected` (i.e. `protected static final`). Always expose as little data as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is not to create `public static` but not `final` fields. Because it can lead to problems with sharing this data between threads.

In your case, you can create a `static final` and **immutable** list.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to have a static list initialized like that:

```
//Static final and unmodifiable list
private static final List<String> listPersons = createListPersons();


private static final createListPersons() {
      List<String> listPersonsTemp = getPersonsFromEnvironmentVariable();
      return Collections.unmodifiableList(listPersonsTemp);
}


public static final List<String> getListPersons(){
  return listPersons;
}
```

This way you ensure that your list will is unmodifiable and accessed only via a getter. In this way the Sonar will not complain about the access modifiers.

Since the List contains  Strings and is unmodifiable it can be considered immutable.

It is safer to use only immutable static objects. State or variables are safer managed in instances.

Answer (score 1):

Using `List.of(...)` from the `java.util.List` package should resolve the SonarQube issue.

> Returns an unmodifiable list containing an arbitrary number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Modifiers should be declared in the correct order
The Java Language Specification recommends listing modifiers in the following order:

```
1. Annotations
2. public
3. protected
4. private
5. abstract
6. static
7. final
8. transient
9. volatile
10. synchronized
11. native
12. strictfp
```

Not following this convention has no technical impact, but will reduce the code's readability because most developers are used to the standard order.

**Noncompliant Code Example**

```
static public void main(String[] args) {   // Noncompliant
}
```

**Compliant Solution**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {   // Compliant
}
```